# Android - Two button calling the same DatePicker have to be clicked twice to work

Tags: android, android-button, android-datepicker

I have an activity with two buttons that call the same DatePicker. 
My activity has to deal with an interval of dates. One button is used for setting the "from" date and the other for the "to" date.

Just after the onCreate of the activity if i click whatever button i want it works well: it calls the DatePicker properly and it goes smooth. If i click the positive button it does all the work it has to do as expected but then, if i want to call again the datePicker, i have to click twice because the first time i click a button it does nothing at all.

So, summing it up:

- click on one button; it works well
- click on the negative button; it all works as expected
- click again; again it works ok
- click on positive button; it works
- click on one button (any of the two); nothing is done except show the button in the pressed state for a brief time
- click again; it works as expected

Here's my code:

public class MyActivity extends ListActivity{

```
private int mYear;
private int mMonth;
private int mDay;

private Date fromDate, toDate;

private Button fromBtn, toBtn;
Calendar cal;

DatePickerDialog datePicker;

static final int DATE_DIALOG_ID = 0;

private int pressedBtn=-1; // 0=from & 1=to

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.myLayout);

    cal = Calendar.getInstance();
    mYear = cal.get(Calendar.YEAR);
    mMonth = cal.get(Calendar.MONTH);
    mDay = cal.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);
    cal.add(Calendar.MONTH, +1);
    this.toDate = cal.getTime();
    cal.add(Calendar.MONTH, -2);
    this.fromDate = cal.getTime();

    SimpleDateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MM-yyyy");
    fromBtn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.frombtn);
    fromBtn.setText(dateFormat.format(fromDate));
    toBtn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.tobtn);
    toBtn.setText(dateFormat.format(toDate));

    datePicker = new DatePickerDialog(this, mDateSetListener, mYear, mMonth, mDay);
    updateDisplay();
}


public void setData(View target) {

    switch(target.getId()) {
    case R.id.frombtn:
        pressedBtn = 0;
        cal.setTime(fromDate);
        break;
    case R.id.tobtn:
        pressedBtn = 1;
        cal.setTime(toDate);
        break;
    }

    mYear = cal.get(Calendar.YEAR);
    mMonth = cal.get(Calendar.MONTH);
    mDay = cal.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);

    datePicker.updateDate(mYear, mMonth, mDay);

    showDialog(DATE_DIALOG_ID);
}


@Override
protected Dialog onCreateDialog(int id) {
    switch (id) {
    case DATE_DIALOG_ID:
        return datePicker;
    }
    return null;
}


private DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener mDateSetListener =
    new DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener() {

    public void onDateSet(DatePicker view, int year, int monthOfYear, int dayOfMonth) {
        mYear = year;
        mMonth = monthOfYear;
        mDay = dayOfMonth;
        updateDisplay();
    }
};


private void updateDisplay() {

    Date date = new Date(mYear-1900, mMonth, mDay);
    SimpleDateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MM-yyyy");

    if(this.pressedBtn==0) {
        this.fromDate = data;
        daBtn.setText(dateFormat.format(fromDate));
    }
    else if(this.pressedBtn==1){
        this.toDate = data;
        aBtn.setText(dateFormat.format(toDate));
    }
    toDate.setHours(23);
    toDate.setMinutes(59);
    toDate.setSeconds(59);
    fromDate.setHours(0);
    fromDate.setMinutes(0);
    fromDate.setSeconds(0);

    //riparte storico
    progDialog = ProgressDialog.show(MyActivity.this, "", "Doing stuff with dates...", true, true);
    Thread thrd = new Thread()
    {
        public void run() {

            ...

        }
    };
    thrd.start();
}
```

}

And here's the layout:

```
<Button
   android:id="@+id/frombtn"
   android:layout_width="100dp"
   android:layout_height="wrap_content"
   android:background="@drawable/textedit_state"
   android:onClick="setData" />

<Button
   android:id="@+id/tobtn"
   android:layout_width="100dp"
   android:layout_height="wrap_content"
   android:background="@drawable/textedit_state"
   android:onClick="setData" />
```

I thought it was something conflicting with the focuses but i used

android:focusable = "false"

and

android:focusableInTouchMode = "false"

for both buttons. I don't have any other clickable item in the view...

I even tried making two different methods for the buttons, two different pickers and two different onDateSetListener; nothing has changed!

Sorry if i'm not very clear but i'm italian...

So, thanks in advance for every help!